# Seach file matching a specific word and assign to variables

Tags: shell-script

There is file in unix eample test1 content are :

```
name1,name2,name3,gourp1,T1
name4,name5,name6,
name7,name8,name9,gourp1,G1
```

Need to find the line which is having word 'group1' , as there are two lines

```
name1,name2,name3,gourp1,T1
name7,name8,name9,gourp1,G1
```

Need to loop these lines  like

loop...lines

```
var1= name1
var2= name2
var3= name3
var4= t1
```

do something..
end

repeat the same thing for next line.

Comment: What are you _using_ the variables for later? Depending on this, you may not want them as shell variables at all, or as an array.  It may be better to do whatever you're doing in `awk` instead, for example.  Parsing data line by line in the shell is not really what you'd want to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you misspelled  group1.

```
grep -w 'group1' test1 | while IFS=',' read -r  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
do
 Something
done
```

The variables will be like:

```
var1=name1
var2=name2
var3=name3
var4=group1
var5=T1
```